# How do I manipulate HTML5 data-* using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

For the HTML DOM element -

```
<div style="border:1px solid; width:100px; background:#FFF" class="btn" data-btnNo="1">Button</div>
```

What is the difference between the two JavaScript lines below?

```
$(this).attr("data-btnNo");
```

and

```
$(this).data("btnNo");
```

According to my [tests on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckTjA/3/), I see that the first one works, while the second does not. And I am trying to understand 'Why?'

Does jQuery maintain a separate data for each DOM elements? According to the [jQuery doc of .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), I get to understand that .data() gets the value in the HTML5 `data-*` into it's own data. Is the reverse true? If I do `$(this).data("myData","jkl345");` will it create an HTML5 attribute `data-myData="jkl345"` on `$(this)`?

I also came across [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) that seems to extend the .data() to apply data to any DOM element.

---

**Added Later:** There seems to be an answer at [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr). The only thing not answered there is does `$(this).data("newDataAttri","myVal")` create `data-newDataAttri="myVal"`? I am beginning to believe that it does not and only stores it in the DOM node. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: `$(this).data("btnno");` works (all lowercase).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes :-) You are right. I just came across http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes which mentions that `data-` should be followed by at least one character that is not A-Z.

Comment: @ManseUK - Thanks. That answers a lot of what I want to know. It did not show up on my search. I think I should have used simpler keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To help debug use the consoles and do `console.log($('.btn').data());` You will see the object and the keys. You need to use '`btnno`' lowercase 'n'

Comment: I had tried console.log() and it did not get me much headway. As @RocketHazmat also pointed, lower case does work :-)